# make: *** No rule to make target for memtier_benchmark performance tool

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile and install the `memtier_benchmark` database performance benchmark tool for Redis and I am running into the error: `make: *** No rule to make target` , even though a Makefile for it does exist in the directory.

```
rw-rw-r-- 1 labuser labuser   2094 Jun  1 22:00 Makefile.am
-rw-rw-r-- 1 labuser labuser  75172 Jun  1 22:01 Makefile.in
```

The write permissions appear to be okay, not sure what could be the problem, but there is a nasty error I do not understand when I run `./configure`:

```
./configure: line 16460: syntax error near unexpected token LIBEVENT_OPENSSL,' ./configure: line 16460: ` PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBEVENT_OPENSSL,'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of the Makefile?

Comment: Is the error message `make: *** No rule to make target ` literally ending in nothing, i.e. no target named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you list are not makefiles.  Makefiles are named `Makefile` or `makefile` (or, if you're using GNU make, `GNUmakefile`).  That's why when you run make, it says "no rule to make target", because there's no makefile defining that rule.

The files `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in` are not actually makefiles, they're *inputs* to autotools which will generate your makefile.  The way you're supposed to use them is to run the `./configure` script.  Once you do that, that script will convert the `Makefile.in` file into a `Makefile`.  Then you can run `make`.

```
./configure
make
```

There should be an `INSTALL` or `README` file that came with the source code that describes this process.

Comment: correct, but I guess I should have made clear when I run the `./configure`, no `Makefile` gets created, what then?

Comment: Did `configure` succeed, or did it generate an error of some kind?  If an error, then you have to solve that problem then when it succeeds it will create your Makefile.  If there was no error, then is there an `INSTALL` or `README` file with the project that tells you to do something different?  If so, read those files and do that thing.  Else, please cut and paste into your question the last 15 or so lines of output from the `configure` script.  I've never heard of a configure script that was supposed to generate a makefile, but didn't after success.

Comment: ahh I totally missed it in the terminal. I got a syntax error: `./configure: line 16460: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBEVENT_OPENSSL,'
./configure: line 16460: `       PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBEVENT_OPENSSL,'`. I am not sure what that `LIBEVENT.OPENSSL` is all about as I am not familiar with this application.

Comment: Looks like that configure script is buggy.  That's too complex a situation to deal with in StackOverflow; you'll have to contact the author of the package and ask them about it.  In any event, please edit your question and cut and paste error messages exactly as seen in the terminal, don't add them as comments: it's too hard to understand without proper formatting etc. and you don't get that in comments.